# Why is GetType() returning DateTime type for Nullable<DateTime>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable type is not a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/nullable-type-is-not-a-nullable-type)

In the following code:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(dt.GetType().ToString());
```

the message box shows "System.DateTime", instead of `Nullable<DateTime>`. The following also returns false (because the GetType is wrong):

```
if (dt.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime?))) 
 ...
```

(btw, using `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` doesn't make a difference)
In the watch window, you have the "Type" column that's displaying the correct type (System.DateTime?).

In my code I have reference to dt as an `object`, so I need to get to the underlying type correctly. How can I do this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/nullable-type-is-not-a-nullable-type which seems to have a good answer

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789(v=VS.100).aspx for some information, but not a solution

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable which has a solution.

Comment: @Chris: it's funny because I've written basically the same answer as the duplicate, without seeing it :D

Comment: `GetType` boxes the value, and since nullables box to their underlying type you get the underlying type from `GetType`. Use `typeof` instead.

Comment: @digEmAll: means you must be right then. ;-) Its one of those questions that I couldn't quite remember the answer to but I *knew* i'd seen on SO before.

Comment: thanks everyone... sorry for a duplicate.... Anyway, this helped me find a bug in framework... submitted on microsoft connect site here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637396/system-windows-forms-binding-cs-doesnt-handle-nullable-type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting [MSDN (How to: Identify a Nullable Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> Calling GetType on a Nullable type
>   causes a boxing operation to be
>   performed when the type is implicitly
>   converted to Object. Therefore GetType
>   always returns a Type object that
>   represents the underlying type, not
>   the Nullable type.

so basically your code is equal to:

```
    DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
    object box = (object)dt;
    Console.Write(box.GetType().ToString());
```

also, looking at ["Boxing Nullable Types"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN we read:

> If the object is non-null -- if
>   HasValue is true -- then boxing
>   occurs, but only the underlying type
>   that the nullable object is based on
>   is boxed. Boxing a non-null nullable
>   value type boxes the value type
>   itself, not the System.Nullable(Of T)
>   that wraps the value type.

this clearly explain the "strange" behavior of `Nullable<T>.GetType()`

Answer (score 4):

`GetType()` uses reflection to return a type. To find out if it's a nullable type you need to check the `PropertyType` value.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in dt.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
    {
       // display nullable info
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because if you write something like this:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
Type t = dt.GetType();
```

It was a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Gave back +1... only because he is a new user here.