# How to get the original Type of a Nullable object?

Tags: c#, object, nullable, gettype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable type is not a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/nullable-type-is-not-a-nullable-type)
>   [How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

See the codes below. Is there a way to get something like System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] by passing n as the argument?

```
static void Test()
{
  List<int> l = new List<int>();
  Nullable<int> n = new Nullable<int>( 1 );
  Console.WriteLine( l.GetType() ); // will output System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
  Console.WriteLine( n.GetType() ); // will output System.Int32. Why won't output something like System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] ?
}
```

Comment: Nullables are boxed, so you can not really have a variable of type `Nullable<T>` well you can but it'll never be that type if you ask it.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable

Comment: @M.Babcock the key points are that the nullable is boxed *when you call `GetType()` on it*, and that boxing a `Nullable<T>` results in a *boxed `T`* (unless the `Nullable<T>` has no value, of course, in which case, boxing it results in a null reference).

Comment: @phoog - Thanks for the clarification. Boxing in C# still confuses me a bit. If I bought something that _looks like_ a dog yet when I ask it what it is and it says it's a cat... which is it???

Comment: @M.Babcock [supercat's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9983291/385844) to one of the duplicate questions discusses this fairly well.

Comment: @phoog - Ohhh, so it's a cat in a dog costume?

Comment: @M.Babcock why yes, I never thought of it that way, but now that you mention it...

Comment: @phoog - It makes sense why a cat would dress up like a dog. Only witches like cats, and they only shop while the pet stores are closed.