# Cannot change type to nullable in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5, casting, nullable

I am creating a generic converter

Here is a sample code of the generic converter

```
bool TryReaderParse<TType>(object data, out TType value)
{
    value = default(TType);
    Type returnType = typeof(TType);
    object tmpValue = null;

    if (returnType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        tmpValue = StringToDatetime(data.ToString());
    }
    else if (returnType == typeof(DateTime?)) // THIS IF FIRES
    {
        tmpValue = StringToNullableDatetime(data.ToString());
    }

    value = (TType)Convert.ChangeType(tmpValue, returnType);  // THROWS
}

public DateTime? StringToNullableDatetime(string date)
{
    DateTime? datetime = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Parse(date, new CultureInfo(Resources.CurrentCulture));
    }

    return datetime;
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
void foo()
{
    DateTime? date = null;
    TryReaderParse<DateTime?>("25/12/2012", out date);
}
```

The thrown exception says that it cannot convert from `DateTime` to `Nullable<DateTime>`. Since, the method creates and returns a nullable type, how come the casting fails?

At the end, I want to have a nullable DateTime, in this particular example.

**edit** The problem is that `StringToNullableDatetime` method returns a `Datetime?` and the casting says that cannot convert from `Datetime`

Since the `StringToNullableDatetime` method returns a nullable datetime, how is it possible that the `Convert.ChangeType` cannot see that the passed argument is nullable?

Ps. I've read answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/nullable-type-is-not-a-nullable-type) one that do the opposite (casting from nullable).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The thrown exception says that it cannot convert from `DateTime` to `Nullable<DateTime>`. Since, the method creates and returns a nullable type, how come the casting fails?

Good question. This fails because *there is no such thing as a boxed nullable*. When you convert a `DateTime?` to `object`, you either get a null reference, if the `DateTime?` was null, or you get the boxed *value*, a `DateTime`. You never get a boxed nullable struct; there is no such thing.

Therefore you end up with either null, or a valid DateTime in that box. You then tell Convert to convert that to a nullable DateTime, and Convert does not know how to do that.

**My advice is that you abandon this line of attack entirely**; this code is borderline abusive of generics. Any time you make a switch on the specific type of a generic, your code is no longer *generic* and you are probably doing it wrong. If you want to do a "try"-style method for datetimes then just write that:

```
DateTime? TryReadDateTime(object data)
{
    ... return null if the object cannot be read as a datetime ...
}
```

Write such a method for *every* type that you intend to read. The user would much rather write:

```
DateTime? d = TryReadDateTime(data);
if (d != null) ...
```

Than

```
DateTime d;
bool b = TryRead<DateTime>(data, out d);
if (b) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx), this line will error if:

> value is null and conversionType is a value type

`Nullable<T>` is a struct and hence a value type, thus you can't use this method call if your value is null. You already handle dates separately, so why use `ChangeType` in those cases anyway?

Comment: edited my question. My problem is that I cannot return a Nullable datetime. The `Convert.ChangeType` line cannot see that the passed argument is nullable

Answer (score 0):

The way nullables, generics, and boxing interact is weird.  You may be better off defining two methods:

```
bool TryReaderParse(object data, out TType value);
bool TryReaderParse(object data, out TType? value) where TType : struct;
```

Within the second method, your code can simply produce a `TType` and assign it to the `TType?` without difficulty.

Comment: First off, a method may not be overloaded on constraints alone. Second, if the method returns a nullable value then *why does it also need to return a bool*? If you're going to do this then the right signatures are `T TryParseClass<T>(object data) where T : class` and `T? TryParseStruct<T>(object data) where T : struct`. No bool necessary.