# How is Nullable<T> different from a similar custom C# struct?

Tags: c#, nullable, language-features, boxing

In [Nullable micro-optimizations, part one](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/), Eric mentions that `Nullable<T>` has a *strange boxing behaviour* that could not be achieved by a similar user-defined type.

What are the special features that the C# language grants to the predefined `Nullable<T>` type? Especially the ones that could not be made to work on a `MyNullable` type.

Of course, `Nullable<T>` has special syntactic sugar `T?`, but my question is more about semantics.

Comment: It was by pure chance that I found your question here. Consider leaving questions like this on the blog posting itself. Also, feel free to email me if you have a question about a posting; there's contact information on the blog's "About" page.

Comment: I did consider it, but I also wanted to learn more about special support other than boxing, so I turned to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I was getting at is: **there is no such thing as a boxed nullable**. When you box an `int`, you get a reference to a boxed `int`. When you box an `int?`, you get either a null reference or a reference to a boxed `int`. You never get a boxed `int?`.

You can easily make your own `Optional<T>` struct, but you can't implement a struct that has that boxing behaviour. `Nullable<T>`'s special behaviour is baked into the runtime.

This fact leads to a number of oddities. For example:

- [C# 4: Dynamic and Nullable<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728752)
- [C# Reflection: How to get the type of a Nullable<int>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550209)
- [Cannot change type to nullable in generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318334)

And FYI there are other ways in which the `Nullable<T>` type is "magical". For instance, though it is a struct type, it does not satisfy the struct constraint. There's no way for you to make your own struct that has that property.

Comment: I see... So if I understand correctly, optimization is the reason for these odd behaviours. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @EldritchConundrum: Not really. Rather, the oddities are a consequence of the mismatch between nullable value semantics and nullable reference semantics. The moral of the story is: add nullability to a type system in v1.0, not v2.0. If nullable reference types and nullable value types were invented at the same time they'd be a lot more similar.

Comment: @EricLippert: How do you think things would be done differently?  My biggest objection to the design of `Nullable<T>` is that--at least by my understanding--in most cases where code gets a `Nullable<T>`, what it wants is a `T` with an indication of whether it's valid; much of the extra stuff around `Nullable<T>` gets in the way of that basic mission.  Do you see things differently?

Answer (score 2):

I found these two in the [C# specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

- The `is` operator works on `T?` as it would have on `T`, and the `as` operator can convert to nullable types.
- Predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types are lifted to the nullable forms of those types.

Now, here are the features that I think are **not** limited to `Nullable<T>`:

- The value in a `switch` can be of a nullable type. I don't think this counts, because switch also accepts user-defined implicit conversions that could be defined on a MyNullable type.
- Nullable IDisposable types are supported, with a null check being inserted before the generated calls to Dispose(). I don't think this counts, because I could define MyNullable as a class and then it would be the same.

Here is what I am not sure about:

- The specs mentions boxing/unboxing and implicit/explicit conversions, but I do not understand whether the same results can be achieved with a MyNullable.

Comment: There is no way to specify that a value type other than `Nullable` should not be convertible to `Object`, or that such the result of conversion should not be an object with the same fields as the struct, initialized to the same values.

Answer (score 2):

C# lifts operators on nullable types.  For example:

```
int? SumNullableInts(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

You would have to do a lot of reflection work in `MyNullable<T>` to support that, and then the following would compile, where it shouldn't:

```
MyNullable<List<string>.Enumerator> SumNullableEnumerators(MyNullable<List<string>.Enumerator> a, MyNullable<List<string>.Enumerator> b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```