# WHY Nullable<T>,struct, allows 'null'

Tags: c#

Nullable is an struct. And i know structs cant be assigned 'null'. So how could we assign Nullable's object a null? What is the reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Nullable<T> is a struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272101/why-nullablet-is-a-struct)

Comment: @ Nolonar: Why it's done? I mean how could a struct object be assigned null? Its not possible for struct object to be assigned null. And Nullable<T> itself is an struct.

Comment: The rules by which *you* have to play are not necessarily the rules by which the compiler and the CLR can play.

Comment: @Sadiq you may also read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13980357/570150

Comment: @ Damien: You mean it is handeled at CLR level??

Comment: No, more, as per p.s.w.g's answer, magic can happen when an apparent assignment of `null` to such a variable occurs - magic that you're not able to write in C# for your own classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't actually accept a value of `null`; it simply has syntactic sugar that allows it to *act* like it's `null`. The type actually looks a bit like this:

```
struct Nullable<T>
{
    private bool hasValue;
    private T value;
}
```

So when it's initialized `hasValue == false`, and `value == default(T)`.

When you write code like

```
int? i = null;
```

The C# compiler is actually doing this behind the scenes:

```
Nullable<T> i = new Nullable<T>();
```

And similar checks are made when casting `null` to an `int?` at run-time as well.

**Further Reading**

- [Why can assign “null” to nullable types](http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/2010/01/26/Why-can-assign-e2809cnulle2809d-to-nullable-types.aspx)

Comment: I think he's wondering why id `DateTime? test = null` possible.

Comment: @ MarcinJuraszek: Yes.. that's what i mean. Or may be because Nullable<T> overloads operator. Like == operator?? Dont know for sure.

Comment: @Sadiq It does override the `Equals` method. But `int? test = null` is actually more of a compiler trick. I've included a link to more detailed information in my answer.