# EF Core Find breaks with Nullable Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using `EF Core 1.1` and `Asp Core 1.1` on Mac

With a model like

```
public class Model {
  public int? Id { get; set; }
  public string OtherProp { get; set; }
}
```

And an action

```
public class ModelController
{
    public Model Get(int? id) 
    {
      DbContext.Set<Model>.Find(id)
    }
}
```

Accessing the url `/model/10` fails with a message `The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<Model>.Find' was of type 'int', which does not match the property type of 'Nullable<int>'`

The error message is clear but my question is if there is a way to make this work, it seems like a very common use case and one that used to work in previous versions.

I tried casting `id` to `int?` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Also, in case it's useful this is [the line that's breaking in EF](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/Internal/EntityFinder.cs#L242)

Comment: Why do you have a private setter (how could the value be set)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that works with EF setting the value, but anyway, I tried making it public and got the same error.

Comment: It was more related to how you would ever be able to bind the model when you submitted a form - it needs to be `public`

Comment: Gotcha, this is an oversimplified example just to focus on the error so I'll edit the setter so that it doesn't make more noise

Comment: how id can be nullable?

Comment: is that a "nullable" primary key? Can primary key be nullable?

Comment: For new instances it can be null, previous versions of EF allowed this. It's a small difference to check `Id.HasValue` vs `Id != 0`. I realize making it `int` would work but it'd be nice to keep it as `int?`

Comment: @jorgehmv - my doubt was whether database supports null for primary key?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code you've already linked: this cannot work, since the CLR gives you always the underlying type for a null-able instance. (Don't know why, had similar issues before...)

In code: `typeof(int?) != ((int?)1).GetType()`.

Thus, comparing the type of the property (`int?`) and the type of the argument will always fail. You have to ask the EF Core team to add support for null-able types for that.

Related: [Nullable type is not a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/785358/2347790)